# if statement is skipped after pressing buttom

Tags: javascript, html

I an a tag that adds one item to cart.

```
<a class="plus" data-href="{% url 'cart_add_one_view' order_item.id %}" href="javascript:void(0)">
            </a>
                {% if order_item.child_product_type %}
                    {{ order_item.count_pack }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ order_item.count }}
                {% endif %}
```

first time in loading the page, if statement is seen and shows order_item.count_pack
but when I press the button, it goes to else and if statement will be ignored so it shows order_item.count. 
when I reload the page the problem solves and it shows order_item.count_pack.
what is the problem and how can I use a tag and not skip if statement?

Comment: Is this a framework? I don't recognize how that should work at all, without.

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:javascript] and [tag:html] but that code is neither.

Comment: this is part of HTML code in frontend @Ouroborus

Comment: @MHB But it's not HTML until after it's parsed. All that `{% %}`stuff is some other framework. You should probably tag your question with whatever that other framework is.